# Make an element as wide as the grandparent

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup where `#content` is 80% wide and contains `.slide` elements. I want the slides to be as wide as their grandparent (i.e. body in this example). This is the markup I have **and it cannot be changed**:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: medium monospace;
  background: lightgray;
}
#content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
}
#content:before,
#content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.slide {
  height: 6em;
  background: indianred;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Phasellus euismod dolor imperdiet!</p>
  </blockquote>
  <div class="slide">Donec mauris tellus</div>
  <p>Pellentesque sit amet venenatis diam, at interdum tortor.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Quisque ornare mi in pharetra porttitor.</li>
    <li>Nulla ultrices quam nec vehicula porta.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried:

- relative-absolute positioning which requires height of slides to be fixed (the slides contain variable length text)
- setting 80% width on paragraphs instead of content but this is not elegant (content contains elements that cannot have 80% width or 10% left margin)

Comment: how does the height you want it to be? like fixed? or keep a legit ratio of the images?

Comment: instead of going this you can just make the `content` `100%` and make all the children inside it to be `80%` except those with class `slide`

Comment: I have revised question and added clarifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your surrounding content can demand a different combination of positioning properties on their own, you could always go with the following.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: medium monospace;
  background: lightgray;
}
#content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
}
#content:before,
#content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.slide {
  height: 6em;
  background: indianred;
  width: 125%; /*100*(100/80)*/
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <div class="slide">Donec mauris tellus</div>
  <p>Pellentesque sit amet venenatis diam, at interdum tortor.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I recommend `100vw` ("virtual width") instead of `125%`, as it is independent of `#content`'s width.

Comment: The parent isn't always necessarily the same width as the viewport, only in this specific case.

Comment: @Siguza `vw` stands for 'viewport width' not virtual width

Comment: I prefer this solution because, as you guessed, the parent may not be the same width as the viewport.

Comment: This math works if the `content` has no scrollbar. With scrollbar the `125%` will be taken from the width of parent minus a width of the scrollbar. The later is unknown with CSS only.

Comment: @Dmitry If `content` has a scrollbar you won't be able to flow an element outside of its bounds anyway. The correct place to control overflow is the parent of `content`, in this case `body`.

Comment: @Etheryte What I mean is that this approach can't be generalized as one would wish. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/DmitryMyadzelets/t6u3kpzL/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
.slide {
  height: 6em;
  background: indianred;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/ecw9xaqt/)

Comment: `vw` seems to count scrollbar too, is it possible to exclude it?

Comment: By default, 100vw is the width of the viewport, scroll bar included.
Set the parent’s overflow property to hidden if the parent should grow along with the content.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser support you require, this is either pretty simple or will require some tricky CSS.

One simple version uses the `vw` ([viewport width unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths)) which has [decent support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) and requires a few simple amends to your setup:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: medium monospace;
  background: lightgray;
}
#content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80vw;
  background: white;
}
#content:before,
#content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.slide {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 6em;
  margin-left: -10vw;
  background: indianred;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <div class="slide">Donec mauris tellus</div>
  <p>Pellentesque sit amet venenatis diam, at interdum tortor.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: medium monospace;
  background: lightgray;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
}
#content:before,
#content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.slide {
  height: 6em;
  background: indianred;
  width: 100vw;
  transform: translateX(-10%);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Phasellus euismod dolor imperdiet!</p>
  </blockquote>
  <div class="slide">Donec mauris tellus</div>
  <p>Pellentesque sit amet venenatis diam, at interdum tortor.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Quisque ornare mi in pharetra porttitor.</li>
    <li>Nulla ultrices quam nec vehicula porta.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use negative margins with corresponding padding + `box-sizing:border-box`

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/d3j22ehx/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: medium monospace;
  background: lightgray;
}
#content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
}
#content:before,
#content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.slide {
  height: 6em;
  background: indianred;
  margin: 0 -12.5%; /* 20% of body = 25% of 80% content... so 12.5% on each side */
  padding: 0 12.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  <blockquote>
    <p>Phasellus euismod dolor imperdiet!</p>
  </blockquote>
  <div class="slide">Donec mauris tellus</div>
  <p>Pellentesque sit amet venenatis diam, at interdum tortor.</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Quisque ornare mi in pharetra porttitor.</li>
    <li>Nulla ultrices quam nec vehicula porta.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead. Here is a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qwja462p/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>

<div class="slide">Donec mauris tellus</div>

<div class="content">
  <p>Pellentesque sit amet venenatis diam, at interdum tortor.</p>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: medium monospace;
  background: lightgray;
}
.content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
}
.content:before,
.content:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.slide {
  height: 6em;
  background: indianred;
}
```