# Getting width of grandparent

Tags: html, css

I want to get the width of grand parent instead of parent. Is it possible with css?

Here is my html and css:

```css
.outter {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;  // In my case is 900px
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 250px;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 1000%; // In my case is 9000px
  height: inherit;
  transition: left 0.5s ease;
}
.outter .inner div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%; //How to get 450px instead of 4500px 
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe `width: 5%` ?

Comment: Yeah, 5% should work.. you know that `.inner` is 1000% of it's parent. To match `.outter .inner div` with the grandparent, you'd need to negate that to 10%. Therefore, 5% would be half of that.

Comment: use width: 5% as a quick hack, or look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29963950/make-an-element-as-wide-as-the-grandparent

Comment: Why not add the 3 divs directly in `outter`? Since inner is an aboslute positioned element relative to `outter`, you can easy position it to look like the 3 dives are inside it.